# MS outlook and PHP

Tags: php, outlook, calendar

It is possible with php create a script, and this script insert an appointment in outlook calendar.
I search in internet but... I don't find a solution... 
I use php but if it is possible with JavaScript is the same.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a link to a [`.ics` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar).

Comment: Yes generate an ICS file, which is just plain text.

Comment: Link to a .ics file is a good idea. I create a .ics file with php but i don't know how import this file... with js? with php? with vbscript?
Thanks

Comment: You need to make a regular link that points to the `.ics` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching again for importing ical files into Outlook - you might even find [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/remotecalendars/)
or even [this](http://bennu.sourceforge.net/)